# pasar datos de un formulario html a una funcion php

Tags: php

Amigos bunas tardes otra vez molestando mis más sinceros agradecimientos a quienes responden, en esto tengo la capacidad para ayudar a otros. Amigos quiero saber si es posible pasar datos de un formulario a una function de .php no he podido lograrlo.

```
 <form action="functioncalling.php" method="POST">
                                <h4>REGISTRAR PRODUCTO</h4>
                                <input type="hidden" name="correo"  class="form-control is-valid"  value="<?php echo $correo ?>"   required>
                                <label for="validation01">Nombre producto</label>
                                <input type="text" name="producto"  class="form-control is-valid" id="validation01"   >
```

Haz click sobre mí :)
                               
No me toma los datos he intentado con javascript y tampoco.

```
Function select(){
 $host = "127.0.0.1";
 $user = "root";
 $clave = "123";
 $bd  = "datosproductos";
 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave,$bd);
 
    $producto=$_POST['producto'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $valor=$_POST['valor'];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO prueba( producto, valor,  correo) VALUES ('$producto','$valor','$correo')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="ok">PRODUCTO REGISTRADO</h3>
            <?php
        } 
    } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Si es posible pasarlos, ¿cuál es el problema o problemas con el código actual?, por favor lee [ask] y trata de exponer de forma un tanto mas clara la duda, por ejemplo en tu código no veo donde invocas a la función, solo la declaras

Comment: Toma en cuenta los typos de tu html por ejemplo no es actio, sino action.

Comment: antes de cerrar form tengo este boton que llama la funtion    <button class="estilosboton" onclick="select()"  type="submit" name="register" id="miBoton">Haz click sobre mí :)</button>

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo podrías recuperar los datos del formulario en una base de datos y después solo hacer una consulta, te adjunto un código que a mi recientemente me funciono

```
<?php

include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['b_alta'])){
    if(strlen($_POST['nombre']) >=1 && strlen($_POST['apellidos']) >=1 && strlen($_POST['correo']) >=1  && strlen($_POST['estado']) >=1 && strlen($_POST['lugar']) >=1){    
        $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos = trim ($_POST['apellidos']);
        $correo = trim($_POST['correo']);
        $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
        $lugar = trim($_POST['lugar']);
        $consulta= "INSERT INTO alta(nombre, apellidos, correo, estado, lugar) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$correo','$estado','$lugar')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        if($resultado){
            ?>
            <h3> ¡Ya se ha dado de alta!</h3>
            <?php
        }else{
            ?>
            <h3>¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
            <?php
        } 
    }else{
            ?>
                <h3>Ha ocurrido un error con la alta</h3> 
            <?php
    }
    
}

?>
```

Comment: Si amigo el problema que tengo es que si llamo la funtion  no lleva el codigo del formulario. voy a intentar con el codigo sugerido mil gracias.